# Crop Some Part of image (in some shape) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, crop

What I want to do is:

I have one image on iPhone screen.

Now, user will move his finger on image. Like he will make circle or triangle or square or star. (No worry, move will have closed loop).

Now when user will complete move means user will make the shape like circle, triangle, or anything then that part of image should be cropped.

Has any one this idea or anything related to this?

Let me know in case of more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Quartz2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) which explains how CoreGraphics can help you do this.

In particular there is a section dedicated to Paths (`NSBezierPaths`), **clipping areas**, Image Masks, and a lot more. In your case, maybe mask but probably more clipping areas are what you will need.

> You can also use a path to constrain the drawing of other objects within the bounds of the path creating, in effect, a clipping area.

*(the capture you see in the doc is a MacOSX Window but of course you can do exactly the same on iPhone, the documentation on Quartz2D is quite generic for both environments)*

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me

```
if (!self.pictureImageViewMasked) {

        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];

        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 0.0)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 50.0)];
        [path closePath];

        if (![[self.pictureImageView layer] mask]) {
            [[self.pictureImageView layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];
        }
        [(CAShapeLayer*)[[self.pictureImageView layer] mask] setPath:[path CGPath]];

        self.pictureImageViewMasked = YES;

    }
```